# Java finding log recursively

Tags: java

I am working on code for my class to recursively find the log of n with the base of b. I am also told to assume that n is exactly b to some integer power. So far I have the following code:

```
public int log(int b, int n ) {
  if (n / b == 1) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return log(b, n / b) + 1;
  }
}
```

When I submit it, it says that I pass all of the test cases except for one hidden test. I am struggling to find what exactly could be wrong with my code since it does not show me what test if failing. I have seen a similar question asked before but the given solution still tells me it is failing a hidden test.

Edit: This is what my results look like. The test cases are predefined and the code is all online. [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBzj6.jpg)

Comment: `since it does not show me what test if failing` ... then your tests aren't very useful.  I think you should step through your test suite in debug mode.

Comment: Sadly it's online so I can debug it. The tests are predefined and this is all it shows me [link](https://imgur.com/a0MC6H4)

Comment: Check all your edge cases, e.g. the log of 0 is undefined, the log of 1 is zero, for any base.

Comment: Thank you, I forgot about checking log of 1. That fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

If `n < b`, then your code will cause a `StackOverflowError`.
This is probably what's missing in your code.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if b == 0? They may be throwing in a mean case eh

Comment: Yeah I tried checking for b == 0 and n == 0 but it gives me the same result. I tried brute forcing it with

return (int) (Math.log(n) / Math.log(b));

but it fixes one hidden test but makes another hidden test fail.